# My links are no more clickable because it is behind other element

Tags: html, css

I need to present a header menu with 3 elements:

- one is left aligned
- one is centered
- one is right aligned

I would like a gray background for this menu.

The problem: if I have links in my left or right elements and it is not clickable because of the centered element.

> How to prevent this problem? or another way of having this kind of menu?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxmf0Lve/

```
<div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="headerLeft">
        <a href="#">Left</a>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTitle">Middle</div>
    <div class="headerRight">
        <a href="#">Right</a>
    </div>
</div>

.headerContainer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
}
.headerTitle {
    position: absolute;
  /*  z-index: -1;  */
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.headerLeft {
    float: left;
}

.headerRight {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: [Is this acceptable](http://jsfiddle.net/sxmf0Lve/1/)?

Comment: Niet is spot on... Otherwise you could add a `z-index` to the floats http://jsfiddle.net/sxmf0Lve/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7mo7hyza/

Your `z-index` idea is good, but you didn't perform it well: `z-index` only works between elements that are both not in the normal workflow of the document (they have `position: absolute/relative/..`)

So you simply have to  position your left/right containers with `position: absolute` instead of `float`, and make the big container `relative` so that you can position the other containers relatively to that one.

```
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
} .headerTitle {
    z-index: 0;
} .headerLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
} .headerRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: why not just use `pointer-events: none;` instead of fiddling with z-index?

Comment: because he's trying to allow clicking on the left and right anchors? @WouterHuysentruit

Comment: Because he may want to still have pointer events on the title

Comment: @Aaron: I ment on `.headerTitle`, but Angivare already justified that

Comment: Avoid z-index for normal layouts like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the left and right position relative and give them a higher z-index.

```css
.headerContainer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
}
.headerTitle {
    position: absolute;
  /*  z-index: -1;  */
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.headerLeft,
.headerRight {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.headerLeft {
    float: left;
}

.headerRight {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="headerLeft">
        <a href="#">Left</a>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTitle">Middle</div>
    <div class="headerRight">
        <a href="#">Right</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `float`-ing elements or messing with the z-index. There are two more appropriate methods for what you're trying to achieve:

**Method 1: CSS box model**

```css
.headerContainer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.headerLeft,
.headerTitle,
.headerRight {
    display: inline-block;
}
.headerLeft,a
.headerRight {
    flex-grow: 0;
}
.headerTitle {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="headerLeft">
        <a href="#">Left</a>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTitle">Middle</div>
    <div class="headerRight">
        <a href="#">Right</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51fnn5L2/)

**Method 2: Table layout**

```css
.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer row">
  <div class="cell">
    <a href="#">Left</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cell middle">
    <h1>Middle</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <a href="#">Right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3sqdnmb/)